# how to add script to the body (similar functionality like method renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response))

Tags: wicket

With the following code, I add trackingpixel to some page `page.html` by overriding the method `renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response)`. This works fine.

page.html looks like this:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/">
    <head>
    ..
    <wicket:container wicket:id="header"></wicket:container>
    </head>
    <body>
      ..
 <script wicket:id="scriptHolder" type="text/javascript" > I would like to add my script here 
</script>
..
    </body>
    </html>
```

TrackingPixel.java:

```
    public abstract class TrackingPixel extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {

            protected TrackingPixel(TrackingPixelType type) {
           ..
        }


        @Override
        public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
                response.renderOnDomReadyJavaScript("WebtrekkInstance = {
                 ..   
                             'path' : 'anyPath',
                     ...:...
                                  ..
                };
");
        }     
             }
```

`renderHead-method`  adds a trackingpixel to the main page. Right mouse click on the page -> source code shows that the following script is added to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

Wicket.Event.add(window, "domready", function(event) {      
            WebtrekkInstance = {
             ..   
                         'path' : 'anyPath',
                 ...:...
                              ..
            };
                        ..            
            ;});
</script>
```

Now I would like to add trackingpixel to a popup. My problem is that I can't add a script to the body. The method `renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response)` doesn't do that, because (I guess) the popup pops up on the same page, so there is only one head and it will not render twice. So I tried to do this with `WebMarkupContainer` as you can see below.

OurServicePopup.java

```
/**
 * Class to display our service as popup
 */
public class OurServicePopupPage<T> extends WebPage {

    public OurServicePopupPage(PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        add(new OurServicePixel());
        super.onInitialize();
    }      
}
```

OurServicePixel.java looks like this:

```
  public class OurServicePopupPixel extends TrackingPixel{
                public OurServicePopupPixel() {
                        }

                WebMarkupContainer scriptContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("scriptContainer");
                @Override
                public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {   
                    scriptContainer.add(new AttributeAppender("type", Model.of("text/javascript")));
                    scriptContainer.add(
                        new AttributeAppender("src","WebtrekkInstance = {
                 ..   
                             'path' : 'anyPath',
                     ...:...
                                  ..
                };
");

          }
              add(scriptContainer); //this shows error
 }
```

The problem here is that I cannot add the scriptContainer.  `add(scriptContainer);` will not work, because `OurServicePopupPixel` is a behaviour and not a page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can simple use a `Label` component with `setEscapeModelStrings(false)`. But it seems a bit strange.

I didn't full understand what is your javascript doing, but maybe you can try to execute it when the DOM is ready. Using a `renderHead` like this:

```
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript( ... YOUR SCRIPT HERE ... ));
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What exactly the script is not importent. I just search for possibility to write smoe script to some placeHolder:   `<body>
 <script wicket:id="scriptHolder" type="text/javascript" > 
</script>
    </body>`

Comment: I think you can use the `Label` component

Comment: Adding label to  `OurServicePopupPage<T>` is easy. But I don't have Idea how can I transfer the script from `OurServicePopupPixel` to `OurServicePopupPage<T>`. `OurServicePopupPixel` is behaviour

Comment: And why it's a Behavior? If you want that your behavior automatically adds a script tag after the component check the `AjaxIndicatorAppender` to see how it's possible.

Comment: I tried this:    `AjaxIndicatorAppender indicator = new AjaxIndicatorAppender(); indicator.bind(new Label("scriptHolder", "script as string");` but no ascript is added to the script holder. `OurServicePopupPixel` is Behaviour because ist extends `TrackingPixel` which in teurn extends `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior`

Comment: I used @jordeu's solution. Here's what my final code looks like:  `String scriptWithTags ="<script .....></script>"  Label trackingScript = new Label("trackingScript",scriptWithTags)  trackingScript.setEscapeModelStrings(false)  trackingScript.setRenderBodyOnly(true)  add(trackingScript)  `  HTML looks like this `<wicket:container wicket:id="trackingScript"></wicket:container>`